# Are there any identities/techniques to simplify a a trigonometric function raised to a large power?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the indefinite integral $$\begin{align}\int{x\sin(2023)\sin^{2023}(x)} dx\end{align}$$ the sine raised to the power of 2023 bothers me. I was hoping that I can reduce the power on that bad boy to make it manageable and any technique in reducing large powers in trig functions will be of great help when I encounter integrals similar to this.

Comment: Is the integrand meant to have $\sin(2023 \color{red}{x})$ instead of $\sin(2023)$? Because as is you just have a constant that can be taken out of the integral.

Comment: @RobertLee Yes, it is a constant.

Comment: @Jaideline, can you add to the body of your question _why_ you're interested in this integral? If perhaps you're trying to solve some definite integral then for some special intervals of integration you can exploit some symmetry to simplify the evaluation of the integral, instead of evaluating the antiderivative explicitly. Without some context of where this integral comes from it's hard to suggest some special tricks that could help you.

Answer (score 2):

$$K=\begin{align}\sin(2023)\int{x\sin^{2023}(x)} dx\end{align}$$

Let $$J_n=\int x\sin^nx\,dx$$

$$K=\ sin(2023)J_{2023}$$

$$J_n=\int x\ sinx \sin^{n-1}x\,dx$$
$$J_n=\sin^{n-1}x\int x\ sinx \,dx-\int (n-1)\sin^{n-2}x\ cosx \int x \ sinx \,dx\,dx$$

Putting in the result;

$$\int x\ sinx \,dx=\ sinx-x\ cosx$$
$$J_n=\sin^{n-1}x(\ sinx-x\ cosx)-\int (\ sinx-x\ cosx) (n-1)\sin^{n-2}x\ cosx\,dx$$
$$J_n=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)+\int (x\ cosx-\ sinx) (n-1)\sin^{n-2}x\ cosx\,dx$$
$$J_n=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)+(n-1)\int (x\ (1-sin^2x)\ sin^{n-2}x-\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)\,dx$$
$$J_n=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)+(n-1)\int \ (x-x\ sin^2x)\ sin^{n-2}x\,dx-\int\ (sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)\,dx$$
$$J_n=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)+(n-1)\int \ (x-x\ sin^2x)\ sin^{n-2}x\,dx-\int\ (sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)\,dx$$
$$J_n=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)+(n-1)\left[\int \ xsin^{n-2}x\,dx-\int x\ sin^nx\,dx-\int\ (sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)\,dx\right]$$
$$J_n=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)+(n-1)\left[J_{n-2}-J_n-\frac{sin^nx}{n}\right]$$

$$J_n=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)+(n-1)J_{n-2}-(n-1)J_n-(n-1)\frac{sin^nx}{n}$$

$$J_n+J_n(n-1)-(n-1)J_{n-2}=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right){sin^nx}$$
$$nJ_n-(n-1)J_{n-2}=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{n-1}x\ cosx)-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right){sin^nx}$$

Put $n=2023$

$$2023J_{2023}-2022J_{2021}=(\ sinx-x\ sin^{2022}x\ cosx)-\left(1-\frac{1}{2023}\right){sin^{2023}x}$$

$$J_{2023}=\frac{1}{2023}\left[(\ sinx-x\ sin^{2022}x\ cosx)-\left(1-\frac{1}{2023}\right){sin^{2023}x}+2022J_{2021}\right]$$

> $$K=\frac{\ sin(2023)}{2023}\left[(\ sinx-x\ sin^{2022}x\
>  cosx)-\left(1-\frac{1}{2023}\right){sin^{2023}x}+2022J_{2021}\right]+C$$

Here's the same integral with the bounds;

$$K=\begin{align}\sin(2023)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x\sin^{2023}(x)} dx\end{align}$$

$$J_n'=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x\sin^{n}(x)} dx$$

$$K=\ sin(2023)J_n'$$
Following the same process;
$$J_n'=\frac{n-1}{n}J_{n-2}+\frac{1}{n^2}$$

$$K=\ sin(2023)\left(\frac{n-1}{n}J_{n-2}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Put $n=2023$

> $$K=\ sin(2023)\left(\frac{2022}{2023}J_{2021}+\frac{1}{(2023)^2}\right)$$